# How to ensure that README.rst is valid?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, travis-ci, restructuredtext

There are two version of my little tool:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tbzuploader/2017.11.0
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tbzuploader/2017.12.0 Bug: The pypi page looks ugly.

In the last update a change in README.rst cases a warning:

```
user@host> rst2html.py README.rst  > /tmp/foo.html
README.rst:18: (WARNING/2) Inline emphasis start-string without end-string.
README.rst:18: (WARNING/2) Inline emphasis start-string without end-string.
```

Now the pypi page looks ugly :-(

I use this recipe to do CI, bumpversion, upload to pypi: https://github.com/guettli/github-travis-bumpversion-pypi

How could I ensure that no broken README.rst gets released any more? With other words I want to avoid that the pypi page looks ugly.

Dear detail lovers: Please don't look into the current particular error in the README.rst. That's is not the question :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**

As of Sep 21, 2018, the Python Packaging Authority recommends an alternative command [`twine check`](https://github.com/pypa/twine#twine-check). To [install twine](https://github.com/pypa/twine#installation):

```
pip install twine
twine check dist/*
```

Note that [twine requires `readme_renderer`](https://github.com/pypa/twine/blob/77b5c75bd683366bcc475e7ae460b1adb79102b4/setup.py#L74).  You could still use `readme_renderer`, and you only need to install twine if you want its other features, which is a good idea anyway if you are releasing to PyPI.

---

From the official Python packaging docs, [Uploading your Project to PyPI](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi):

> **Tip:** The reStructuredText parser used on PyPI is **not** Sphinx! Furthermore, to ensure safety of all users, certain kinds of URLs and directives are forbidden or stripped out (e.g., the `.. raw::` directive). **Before** trying to upload your distribution, you should check to see if your brief / long descriptions provided in `setup.py` are valid. You can do this by following the instructions for the [pypa/readme_renderer](https://github.com/pypa/readme_renderer) tool.

And from that tool's `README.rst`:

> To check your long description's locally simply install the `readme_renderer` library using:

```
$ pip install readme_renderer
$ python setup.py check -r -s
```

Comment: Great. Yes you are right. The readme_renderer has the authoritative answer if the REAME is valid or not. Thank you!

Comment: Now I have the tool to do this. My next step is how to call it. Up to now I see two ways: use subprocess or use it like a library. Maybe there is a third way. I am unsure what is better.

Comment: @guettli are you asking a separate question? If so please create one. Otherwise please accept this answer if it did in fact solve your problem.

Comment: This command says it was deprecated in favor of `twine check`, but doesn't give a full set of instructions on where to how to install this.

Comment: @AlanSE where do you see deprecation of `readme_renderer`? `twine check` uses it.

Comment: For historical documentation, running the pip install & setup.py as check gave me "warning: Check: This command has been deprecated. Use `twine check` instead". It looks like you have already updated your answer. Exact use of that would vary by project, but `python setup.py install` and then `twine check dist/*` works for the particular one I was testing, and is a not-deprecated way of doing this now.

Answer (score 4):

**Preamble**

I had a readme which would not render on PyPi, other than the first element on the page (an image).  I ran the file against multiple validators, and tested it against other renders.  It worked perfectly fine everywhere else! So, after a long, nasty fight with it, and numerous version bumps so I could test a PyPi revision, I tried reducing the file to a bare minimum, from which I'd build it back up.  It turned out that the **first line was always processed, and then nothing else was**...

**Solution**

Discovering this clue regarding the first line, I then had an epiphany...  All I had to do was **change the line endings** in the file!  I was editing the file in Windows, with Windows line endings being tacked on implicitly.  I changed that to Unix style and (poof!) PyPi fully rendered the doc!

**Rant...**

I've encountered such things in the past, but I took it for granted that PyPi would handle cross platform issues like this.  I mean one of the key features of Python is being cross platform!  Am I the first person working in Windows to encounter this?!  I don't appreciate the hours of time this wasted.

Comment: Please tell this the pypi developers, too.

Comment: I'll look into filing a bug report, as you suggest.

Comment: @BuvinJ , can you please provide some information about the tool which you have used in order to change the line endings?

Comment: I normally use Notepad++ for this on Windows.  Go to Edit... EOL Conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You could try if [rstcheck](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rstcheck) catches the type of error in your readme. If it does, run it after pytest in your script section. (and add it in your requirements ofc).