# How to integrate checking of readme in pytest

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

I use `pytest` in my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/guettli/reprec/blob/master/.travis.yml) to check my code.

I would like to check the README.rst, too.

I found [readme_renderer](https://github.com/pypa/readme_renderer) via this StackO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46687472/633961)

Now I ask myself how to integrate this into my current tests.

The docs of readme_renderer suggest this, but I have not clue how to integrate this into my setup:

```
python setup.py check -r -s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I check it like this now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, unicode_literals, print_function

import os
import subx
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_readme_rst_valid(self):
        base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
subx.call(cmd=['python', os.path.join(base_dir, 'setup.py'), 'check', '--metadata', '--restructuredtext', '--strict'])
```

Source: https://github.com/guettli/reprec/blob/master/reprec/tests/test_setup.py

Comment: I am not really happy with above solution. I gave a bounty to find a better solution.

Comment: @guettli, check the answer I posted and see if it is of any help

Comment: A simple solution without calling a subprocess would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest and most robust option is to write a pytest plugin that replicates what the [distutils command](https://github.com/pypa/readme_renderer/blob/master/readme_renderer/integration/distutils.py) you mentioned in you answer does.

That could be as simple as a [conftest.py](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html) in your test dir. Or if you want a standalone plugin that's distributable for all of us to benefit from there's a nice [cookiecutter template](https://github.com/pytest-dev/cookiecutter-pytest-plugin).

Ofc there's inherently nothing wrong with calling the check manually in your script section after the call to pytest.

Comment: Do you think I need to write a plugin? Why not write a simple test?

Comment: TBH I didn't even think about using a simple test. Using a test has the disadvantage that you're not in control of how a potential error is reported and pytest defaults to suppress any output from called code. Writing a plugin gives you control over that. Other than that you'd be fine just calling the readme_renderer API from a test like in the distutils command I linked.

Comment: yes, calling the readme_renderer via subprocess from a test is not a nice solution, since I want to see the error message.

Comment: @guetli if you are interested in the rst syntax validation output, I updated my answer with an example how to get the error message as string in the test.

Answer (score 3):

So I implemented something but it does require some modifications. You need to modify your `setup.py` as below

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup_info = dict(
    name='so1',
    version='',
    packages=[''],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='tarun.lalwani',
    author_email='',
    description=''
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(**setup_info)
```

Then you need to create a symlink so we can import this package in the test

```
ln -s setup.py setup_mypackage.py
```

And then you can create a test like below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, unicode_literals, print_function

import os
import unittest
from distutils.command.check import check
from distutils.dist import Distribution

import setup_mypackage

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_readme_rst_valid(self):
        dist = Distribution(setup_mypackage.setup_info)
        test = check(dist)
        test.ensure_finalized()
        test.metadata = True
        test.strict = True
        test.restructuredtext = True

        global issues
        issues = []

        def my_warn(msg):
            global issues
            issues += [msg]
        test.warn = my_warn

        test.check_metadata()
        test.check_restructuredtext()

        if len(issues) > 0:
            assert len(issues) == 0, "\n".join(issues)
```

Running the test then I get

```
...
AssertionError: missing required meta-data: version, url
missing meta-data: if 'author' supplied, 'author_email' must be supplied too

Ran 1 test in 0.067s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

This is one possible workaround that I can think of

Comment: The other answer of user "guettli" is much shorter. Why is you solution better?

Comment: I assumed the bounty was opened after accepting that answer. The intent of the bounty was to get an alternative answer which doesn't use subprocess and is able to do the same thing using a normal pytest test case. So better or not this is one of the ways you would do it using a pure python script instead of subprocessing setup.py

Answer (score 2):

Upvoted because checking readme consistence is a nice thing I never integrated in my own projects. Will do from now on!

I think your approach with calling the `check` command is fine, although it will check more than readme's markup. `check` will validate the complete metadata of your package, including the readme if you have `readme_renderer` installed.

If you want to write a unit test that does only markup check and nothing else, I'd go with an explicit call of `readme_renderer.rst.render`:

```
import pathlib
from readme_renderer.rst import render

def test_markup_is_generated():
    readme = pathlib.Path('README.rst')
    assert render(readme.read_text()) is not None
```

The `None` check is the most basic test: if `render` returns `None`, it means that the readme contains errors preventing it from being translated to HTML. If you want more fine-grained tests, work with the HTML string returned. For example, I expect my readme to contain the word "extensions" to be emphasized:

```
import pathlib
import bs4
from readme_renderer.rst import render

def test_extensions_is_emphasized():
    readme = pathlib.Path('README.rst')
    html = render(readme.read_text())
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
    assert soup.find_all('em', string='extensions')
```

---

**Edit**: If you want to see the printed warnings, use the optional `stream` argument:

```
from io import StringIO

def test_markup_is_generated():
    warnings = StringIO()
    with open('README.rst') as f:
        html = render(f.read(), stream=warnings)
        warnings.seek(0)
        assert html is not None, warnings.read()
```

Sample output:

```
tests/test_readme.py::test_markup_is_generated FAILED
================ FAILURES ================
________ test_markup_is_generated ________

    def test_markup_is_generated():
        warnings = StringIO()
        with open('README.rst') as f:
            html = render(f.read(), stream=warnings)
            warnings.seek(0)
>           assert html is not None, warnings.read()
E           AssertionError: <string>:54: (WARNING/2) Title overline too short.
E             
E             ----
E             fffffff
E             ----
E             
E           assert None is not None

tests/test_readme.py:10: AssertionError
======== 1 failed in 0.26 seconds ========
```