# PyPi: How to upload documentation and how to change the package description?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pypi

#### 1. Documentation

How can I add the zipped sphinx documentation to a package on PyPi?
There used to be an `upload documentation` button, but this was replaced by a `destroy documentation` one. This button does exactly what it says. I destroyed my old docs -.-

Still, even after wiping out my old docs, the button is still there, I cannot upload the new docs.

#### 2. Package info

Moreover, can I change the package description on PyPi? My `Readme.md` file contains badges that are not interpreted by pypi (see [my pypet package on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypet/0.4.1)), but that are known to github. I need to manually remove them from the package description. How can I do this? There used to be a button for this, too...

Comment: Btw, I am still amazed how sub-optimal the python package repo remains after all this years. Wasn't this supposed to be replace by something called warehouse a year ago or so?

Comment: How much money have you donated for the free hosting?

Comment: Just 5 bucks :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Packages docs hosting has been decommissioned. Use [ReadTheDocs](https://readthedocs.org/).
2. Don't use Markdown for README — use reStructuredText. GitHub understand reST README if it's named `README.rst`.

Comment: +1 for RTD. Also see my answer regarding [readme.rst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682793/how-to-ensure-that-readme-rst-is-valid/46687472#46687472).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm already on RTD, I used Pythonhosted as an alternative.

Comment: In case I use rst, does this support badges (like the one from coveralls showing test coverage)? If not, how can I have badges on gtihub and at the same time not on pypi? I simply used to delete the badges from pypi manually after a deployment. But this doesn't work any longer?

Comment: It does. See my examples: [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLObject), [source at github](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/setup.py#L80).

Comment: Here's an amazing answer with all the references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2747041/3339058