# README.rst fails to render on PyPi when using `raw` directive

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pypi

I have a `README.rst` in my project hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/aishpant/attribute-documentation/). It renders fine on GitHub but fails to render on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/abi2doc/1.3) i.e. I see raw content on the PyPi project description page.

I have looked through similar questions and checked the rst format using `python setup.py -r` and the packages [rstcheck](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rstcheck) & [collective.checkdocs](https://github.com/collective/collective.checkdocs), all of which do not throw any errors. There are no relative links or internal links. I am not sure what the problem is here and how I can fix this.

**I know** this question has been asked many times. I think I have tried all the solutions and they did not work for me and that is why I am asking again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See my answer at [How to ensure that README.rst is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682793/how-to-ensure-that-readme-rst-is-valid/46687472#46687472)

```
python setup.py check -r -s
running check
warning: Check: :11: (WARNING/2) "raw" directive disabled.

warning: Check: Invalid markup which will not be rendered on PyPI.

error: Please correct your package.
```

To fix, don't use the `raw` directive, and instead use [`image` directive with its various attributes](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image):

```
.. image:: https://plot.ly/~aishpant/1.png?share_key=8mG4JmyySLLYjbjTg7Uy62
   :target: https://plot.ly/~aishpant/1/?share_key=8mG4JmyySLLYjbjTg7Uy62
   :align: center
   :alt: sysfs line plot
   :width: 600px
```

Comment: Works! Thank you! I had been struggling with this for hours :-)

Comment: Also `twine check dist/*` per https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/

Comment: ... I found that the twine check can report that PyPi with not render an rst, which in fact it will.  So, it seems this "official" procedure is not valid (at least currently).

Comment: It helped me to understand the syntax issues inside my .rst. Thank you @steven piercy